# CSS3: как адаптировать анимацию под разные размеры экрана?

Tags: html, css3, анимация, css-animation

Есть блок, который становится видимым на устройствах шириной экрана < 767px. В нём посредством анимации движется лента картинок - туда и обратно:

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 767px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-1140px);
    }
}

img.movepics {
    animation: move 10s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.imageup.ru/img78/2926184/lenta.jpg" alt="" class="movepics" />
</div>
```

При размере экрана в 767px лента (чтобы её можно было просмотреть целиком) должна смещаться на 1140px. Но если экран будет меньше, то смещение, соответственно, должно увеличиваться, иначе часть ленты останется за кадром.

Вручную подгонять смещение под каждые 5-10px - не вариант. С процентами тоже работает криво.

Как сделать, чтобы лента картинок на любом экране "доезжала" до своего конца и возвращалась обратно?

Comment: Может лучше картинки нарезать и засунуть в блоки и в Bootstrap Carousel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в анимацию отступ и двигайте на 100%:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 767px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}

img.movepics {
  transform: translateX(0);
  margin-left: 0;
  display: block;
  animation: move 10s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.imageup.ru/img78/2926184/lenta.jpg" alt="" class="movepics" />
</div>
```

Comment: Плюсую Ваш ответ - он лучший из всего, что тут предлагали. Но есть одно но: анимация теперь движется с едва заметными рывками. Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: Добавила переход от нулевого значения и вендоры, возможно у вас старая версия, у меня не было рывков и до этого. Посмотрите, помогло? И где проверяете?

Comment: у меня хром 62.0.3202.94. Вендорные префиксы не помогли, увы. Запустите одновременно мой исходник и Ваш вариант - посмотрите. Исходник плавнее движется.

Comment: проверил сейчас в Opera 49.0.2725.47 - тоже есть небольшие рывки время от времени

Comment: Нашла почему пропадает плавность. Не все изменения CSS свойств могут быть обработаны напрямую через GPU. А поддерживаемые свойства только: transform, opacity, filter. А я добавляю margin.

Comment: [Аппаратное ускорение в CSS анимации](https://webformyself.com/apparatnoe-uskorenie-v-css-animacii/) - хорошая статья

Comment: Даже не знаю, думаю возможно сохранить плавность если анимацию сдвига закинуть вовнутрь анимации сдвига, т.к. просто с помощью одного transition сложить ширины не получится.

Comment: вот я как раз пытался использовать calc(), но почему-то углы в rotate складываются, а проценты и пиксели в translate - нет ((

Answer (score 2):

Единица измерения vw тут лучше всего подойдет, svitch, прав...  Просто я бы на твоем месте не img использовал, а обычный div, так как его background-ом легче манипулировать...  Мой пример конечно не идеален, не знаю какие именно размеры тебе нужны.  Остальное подгонишь под себя... По крайней мере при любом при любом разрешении ведет себя одинаково, как ты и хотел...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 60vw;
  max-height: 19vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 19vw;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-105.2vw);
  }
}

.movepics {
  width: 166vw;
  height: 19vw;
  max-height: 19vw;
  background-image: url(http://www.imageup.ru/img78/2926184/lenta.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  animation: move 30s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="movepics"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не, никакие конкретные размеры как раз не нужны - почему у тебя width для .wrapper задан? это не адаптивное решение ((

Comment: Ну можешь убрать, если надо... Но  при VW это вполне адаптивно...

Comment: @Air интересное решение - лови(+)

Comment: @Air, убрал - и стало как у меня )) Мне надо, чтобы при экранах 767 и меньше картинка шла во весь экран, но двигалась только до своего конца, а затем шла назад.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, не все ценят.. как видишь)))  следом за тобой кто-то уже минус поставил...  ))  благодарю, Alexandr_T

Comment: @Air, ну и вариант с background, конечно, не годится - нужно именно так, как у меня в исходнике

Comment: ну тогда используй img...

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить движение пропорционально ширине экрана в vw-юнитах.
2. Установить для каждого разрешения ("брейкпоина") свою величину движения блока.

В первом случае:

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 767px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100vw);
    }
}

img.movepics {
    animation: move 10s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.imageup.ru/img78/2926184/lenta.jpg" alt="" class="movepics" />
</div>
```

Comment: ого впервые вижу vw юнит @svitch

Comment: "ширина экрана" нигде не задаётся - на каждом устройстве она своя. и никаких "брейкпоинтов" тоже нету - анимация должна быть резиновой, адаптироваться под каждый пиксель

Comment: transform: translateX(-100vw) - здесь "100vw" ширина экрана в формате viewport units. п.с. уточнил ответ.

Comment: @svitch ну и? )) запустите свой пример и Вы увидите, что он не работает как надо - лента не доезжает до конца

Comment: win7, latest Chrome - в примере как раз доезжает

Comment: @svitch, а у меня - не доезжает. А надо, чтобы у всех пользователей доезжала

Comment: какой браузер (и его версия) у вас?

Comment: @svitch, win7, хром 62.0.3202.94

Comment: Всё, увидел. Похоже, что проблема в прокрутке на начало и что в конце движения картинка "перескакивает на начало". Посмотрите вот этот код: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EyxPPm - здесь используется два блока и один подменяет другой в конце движения.

Comment: @svitch, ничего не происходит по Вашей ссылке. Но я посмотрел код - там какой-то фарш (( Никакой подмены мне не надо - надо просто понять, как сделать анимацию "резиновой"

Answer (score 0):

Пример со свойствами поддерживаемыми GPU:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 767px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes helpermove {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.helper {
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: helpermove 10s linear alternate infinite;
}

.movepics {
  will-change: transform;
  margin-left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
  animation: move 10s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="helper">
    <img src="http://www.imageup.ru/img78/2926184/lenta.jpg" alt="" class="movepics" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня всё равно дёргается (( не постоянно, а периодически, в какой-то момент начинает подтормаживать

Comment: Даа, вроде бы прописаны возможные хаки, но мне кажется меньше дергается, чем предыдущий вариант. Остается надеяться, что в скором будущем технологии будут прогрессивнее, браузеры умнее, устройства быстрее)